# undefined index data laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i'm integrating this login api on laravel:

endpoint: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/v1/users/login/`

parameter:

```
 {"data":{ 

"email":"admin@mail.com", 

"password":"admin@123", 

"user_type":"1", 

"encrypted":false 

},"encoded_data":"yes"}
```

controller:

i'm posting data from form:

```
    $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'user_type' => 'required'
        ]);

            $ds = $request->all();
            
            $url = $this->base_api_url . 'api/v1/users/login/';

            $apiRequest = [
                'data' => [
                    'email' => $ds['username'],
                    'password' => $ds['password'],
                    'user_type' => $ds['admin'],
                    'encrypted' => false
                ],
                'encoded_data' => 'yes',
            ];
            
            $apiResponse = Http::acceptJson()->post($url, $apiRequest);
            dd($apiResponse);
```

its return:

```
{"error":1,"success":false,"message":"Undefined index: data"}
```

this is the parameter i'm sending in $apiRequest:

```
array:2 [▼

"data" => array:4 [▼
    "email" => "admin@mail.com"
    "password" => "admin@123"
    "user_type" => "1"
    "encrypted" => false
  ]
  "encoded_data" => "yes"
]
```

api working fine on postman:

[image]

Comment: Where is your login logic? i mean have you used token or something else?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya for login it doesn't need token

Comment: Add a snippet for your login validation and data handling

Comment: @joekenpat i'm using default validation please see the edited code

Comment: Add your login api implementation too.

Comment: @Nandan let take this to [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235591/undefined-index-data-laravel) so i can try to assist you.

Comment: @joekenpat i'm not able to send message on chat room

Answer (score 0):

I think you are requesting json format data so you need to get with by using this`$request->json()->all()` by using this you can access the key value.

Comment: i'm getting form data

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `Http::post` sends a normal post request (form data). You should also send the `Content-type: application/json` header so the Laravel API understands it.

Try using the following:

```php
$apiResponse = Http::accept('application/json')->post($url, $apiRequest);
// or
$apiResponse = Http::acceptJson()->post($url, $apiRequest);
```